# DynamicGrid Crashing Because Of NullPointerException

Tags: android, gridview, nullpointerexception, baseadapter, dynamicgridview

i will use askerov's dynamicgridview library in my project but i got a nullpointerexception sometimes when i test application. I have 100 item in my gridview and when i drag an item to bottom. Last 7 line don't animate and app crashed like below. When i have 84 item last 5 line don't animate and app crashed. Finally when i have 50 or less than 50 item last 2 line don't animate and app crashed.

I try to use try catch but library crashed different code line. I try to change adapter. Like;

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CheeseViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.grid_item, null);
        holder = new CheeseViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (CheeseViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.build(getItem(position).toString());
    return convertView;
}
```

I set different tag each item. App crashed cell animation section. I didn't solve this problem. How do you approach this problem?

```
private Point getColumnAndRowForView(View view) {
    int pos = getPositionForView(view);
    int columns = getColumnCount();
    int column = pos % columns;
    int row = pos / columns;
    return new Point(column, row);
}


03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at android.widget.AdapterView.getPositionForView(AdapterView.java:600)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at net.mertsaygi.ustalibrary.DynamicGridView.getColumnAndRowForView(DynamicGridView.java:904)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at net.mertsaygi.ustalibrary.DynamicGridView.handleCellSwitch(DynamicGridView.java:690)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at net.mertsaygi.ustalibrary.DynamicGridView.access$14(DynamicGridView.java:681)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at net.mertsaygi.ustalibrary.DynamicGridView$2.checkAndHandleFirstVisibleCellChange(DynamicGridView.java:1097)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at net.mertsaygi.ustalibrary.DynamicGridView$2.onScroll(DynamicGridView.java:1027)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1520)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5552)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4677)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:524)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
03-22 12:26:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(9461):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you please tell in which line are you getting the exception

Comment: int pos = getPositionForView(view); this line

Comment: Here getPositionForView is a method written by you?? If yes please post it.

Comment: This is adapterview's method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getPositionForView(android.view.View)

Comment: Debug the code using debugger u will get to know exactly what is null